# Specifying Region in Dataflow reading BigQuery Dataset python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read in a bigquery dataset in dataflow. It cannot find the bigquery dataset/table that I specify.

job_name is preprocess-ga360-190523-130005

my datalab vm, gcs bucket, and bigquery dataset are all location in europe-west2.

For some reason, it is searching for the dataset in location 'US'

```
modules versions are apache-beam 2.5.0,google-cloud-dataflow 2.0.0, google-cloud-bigquery 0.25.0
```

Searched documentation and couldn't come up for an answer as to why this is happening.

```
OUTPUT_DIR = "gs://some-bucket/some-folder/"

#dictionary of pipeline options
options = {
    "staging_location": "gs://some-bucket/some-folder/stage/"
    "temp_location": "gs://some-bucket/some-folder/tmp/"
    "job_name": job_name,
    "project": PROJECT,
    "runner": "DirectRunner",
    "location":'europe-west2',
    "region":'europe-west2',
}

#instantiate PipelineOptions object using options dictionary
opts = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags = [], **options)

#instantantiate Pipeline object using PipelineOptions
with beam.Pipeline(options=opts) as 
    outfile = "gs://some-bucket/some-folder/train.csv"
    (
      p | "read_train" >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query = 
my_query, use_standard_sql = True))
        | "tocsv_train" >> beam.Map(to_csv)
        | "write_train" >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.WriteToText(outfile))
    )
print("Done")
```

Response:

> HttpError: HttpError accessing
>   https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projects/queries/querystring:
>   response: <{'status': '404', 'content-length': '342',
>   'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
>   'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
>   'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control':
>   'private', 'date': 'Thu, 23 May 2019 13:00:08 GMT', 'x-frame-options':
>   'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>,
>   content <{   "error": {
>       "code": 404,
>       "message": "Not found: Dataset my_dataset:views was not found in location US",
>       "errors": [
>         {
>           "message": "Not found: Dataset my_dataset:views was not found in location US",
>           "domain": "global",
>           "reason": "notFound"
>         }
>       ],
>       "status": "NOT_FOUND"   } }

Answer (score 1):

In Apache Beam 2.5.0 Python SDK, [non US query sources weren't yet supported](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/093ac64bc2d59f3d58c0f0e7f65f2a36eaf26a4a/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L647).

It looks like support was added in Apache Beam 2.8.0 Python SDK [[Release Notes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12319527&version=12343985), [PR](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/6463), [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1909)].